# Using rsync on windows with vagrant running a CoreOS VM

Tags: windows, cygwin, vagrant, rsync, coreos

I am using windows 8.1 Pro pc running vagrant and cygwin's rsync.

I am configuring as such:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../sharedFolder", "/vagrant_data", type: "rsync"
```

And when I execute `vagrant up` I get the following error:

```
C:\dev\vagrantBoxes\coreOS>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'yungsang/coreos' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: core
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Rsyncing folder: /c/dev/vagrantBoxes/sharedFolder/ => /vagrant_data
There was an error when attempting to rsync a synced folder.
Please inspect the error message below for more info.

Host path: /c/dev/vagrantBoxes/sharedFolder/
Guest path: /vagrant_data
Command: rsync --verbose --archive --delete -z --copy-links --chmod=ugo=rwX --no-perms --no-owner --no-group --rsync-path sudo rsync -e ssh -p 2222 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/d
ev/null -i 'C:/Users/aaron.axisa/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key' --exclude .vagrant/ /c/dev/vagrantBoxes/sharedFolder/ core@127.0.0.1:/vagrant_data
Error: Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
rsync: change_dir "/c/dev/vagrantBoxes/sharedFolder" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(1052) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I assume it is an issue with how it is changing the directory path to /c/dev rather than C:\dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing, if you are using cygwin, use the solution by @osroot25 .

If you are using cwRsync and do *not* have cygwin, there is no workaround *using Vagrant* except editing the source code as @Andrew Myers details.  Tested using Vagrant v1.6.5.

My workaround that works for me is to bypass Vagrant altogether and use cwRsync directly.  This works for me because I am syncing a folder that hardly ever changes.  I might change it quite a few times in one day (so I have to remember step 2 below each time), but I then go weeks (or months) without any changes.  Remember that to use cwRsync you have to edit and use the cwrsync.cmd script.  Attempting to access the rsync.exe command directly or by adding it to your path will **fail**.  Step 1: I added the following line to the end of cwrsync.cmd (in the installed folder):

`rsync -re "ssh -p 2222" /cygdrive/b/VCS/packages/ vagrant@localhost:packages --exclude ".git/"`

Step 2:  I have a separate cmd window open that I run the cwrsync.cmd using the full path.  Then if I need to sync changes onto the VM, I activate that window, *up-arrow, return* and updating is instant!

Modifying ENV to set cygwin fix by @osroot25 doesn't work with cwRsync because when you force cygwin detection, the "vagrant ssh" command will not work because it **requires** the cygpath command in cygwin, which you won't have, so you cannot ssh into the VM.  Well you can if you use the ssh command directly with all the right options.

Answer (score 7):

like I commented in the github-issue, following line in your Vagrantfile will most certainly fix your problem

`ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"] = ENV["VAGRANT_DETECTED_OS"].to_s + " cygwin"`

since this is local in your Vagrantfile, the source-files can be kept untouched

Answer (score 3):

workaround: just `ln -s /cygdrive/c/ /c` on cygwin terminal

Answer (score 2):

There is a hacky way to fix this (worked for me anyway) where you have to change

```
hostpath = Vagrant::Util::Platform.cygwin_path(hostpath)
```

to

```
hostpath = "/cygdrive" + Vagrant::Util::Platform.cygwin_path(hostpath)
```

on line 43 in `C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\gems\gems\vagrant-[VERSION]\plugins\synced_folders\rsync\helper.rb`

It's different for 1.5.x, you can read this thread here about it: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3230

I will, however, be the first to admit that editing the core is far from ideal.